# How to work with tactile devices?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am stuck on this problem : I want to execute an action when the user clicks with the pen device on a Table row (or cell) if the device is a tactile one ( for example the DefaultFxTouchPhone1 with Sun JavaME WirelessToolkit SDK 3.0 ). I tried to use the `addFocusListener` method but it has bugs because even though the Form which displays the Table is not shown anymore then the `FocusGain` method is still called !

So how to capture the pen click event only when the actual Form is shown ?

Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , I added the `pointerListener` to the Form , and I implemented the `pointerPressed` method into which I test if the x and y coordinates of the `pointerPressed` method is between the first `absoluteX` and last `absoluteY` ( plus the height ) of the Table cell. And it works !

Answer (score 1):

`LookAndFeel.setTactileTouchDuration(int)` is probably what you need.

Comment: This method sets the duration of the vibration. What I need is to capture the click event on a Table cell when the device is a touch screen device. So how to execute an action when the user clicks on a Table cell ?